# Iterating over numpy array and access the values

Tags: python, numpy

I want to iterate over a numpy array and do some calculations on the values. However, things are not as expected. To show what I mean, I simply wrote this code to read values from a numpy array and move them to another list.

```
a = array([1,2,1]).reshape(-1, 1)
u = []
for i in np.nditer(a):
    print(i)
    u.append(i)
print(u)
```

According to [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_iterating_over_array.htm), `nditer` points to elements and as `print(i)` shows, `i` is the value. However, when I append that `i` to an array, the array doesn't store the value. The expected output is `u = [1, 2, 1]` but the output of the code is

```
1
2
1
[array(1), array(2), array(1)]
```

What does `array(1)` mean exactly and how can I fix that?

P.S: I know that with `.tolist()` I can convert a numpy array to a standard array. However, in that code, I want to iterate over numpy elements.

Comment: If you would print the type of `i`, you would see that its of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: Is there a reason why you reshaped? From that you get an object with shape (3, 1) and if you iterate over those items you get an `array` with one element in it.

Comment: the real question is **why would you use `np.nditer` on the first place?**

Comment: By default, iterating over an array of dimension d>1 only iterates through the first axis, and considers it as an array of dimension d-1. You're reshaping `a` to be an array of shape `(3,1)`, which makes it a d=2 array, so each iteration will return a d=1 array. If you flatten it first, it will do the trick : `for i in a.flatten(): u.append(i)`

Comment: @mozway: I tried nditer because I saw that in some tutorials. In fact I didn't check the type of `i` and that `print(i)` misguided me.

Comment: Those tutorials misled you.  `nditer` is an advanced iterator that has little value in python code. It's only confusing and complicating your case.

Comment: All the tutorial examples just print the iteration variable, showing its current value. While it is possible to modify its values, I've never seen anyone try to collect them as you do.  Your list ends up with multiple references to the **same** object, all of which show  its final value.  List append can be tricky in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained in your previous question, `numpy.nditer` yields **numpy arrays**. What is shown by print is only the representation of the object, not the content or type of the object (e.g., `1` and `'1'` have the same representation, not the same type).

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,1]).reshape(-1, 1)

type(next(np.nditer(a)))
# numpy.ndarray
```

You just have a zero-dimensional array:

```
np.array(1).shape
# ()
```

There is no need to use `numpy.nditer` here. If you really want to iterate over the rows of your array with single column (and not use  `tolist`), use:

```
u = []
for i in a[:,0]:
    u.append(i)
u
# [1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I would also add that calling string on a python list calls the `__repr__` method on each element inside. For some items, `__str__` and `__repr__` are the same, but this is not the case

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.nditer` actually returns a numpy array. If you want the actual value of this item, you can use the built in `item()` function:

```
a = array([1,2,1]).reshape(-1, 1)
u = []
for i in np.nditer(a):
    u.append(i.item())
print(u)
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure python equivalent of what's happening with your append is:

```
In [75]: alist = []
    ...: x = [0]
    ...: for i in range(3):
    ...:     x[0] = i
    ...:     print(x)
    ...:     alist.append(x)
[0]
[1]
[2]
In [76]: alist
Out[76]: [[2], [2], [2]]
In [77]: x
Out[77]: [2]
```

`x` is modified in each loop, but only a reference is saved.  The result is that all elements of the list are the same object, and display its last value.